# Window.open only open url, does not click - click has to be done manually

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm using window.open and on click, it opens a new window, pre-fills the address bar but does not open the url filled in the address bar (for chrome)

```
window.open("www.stackoverflow.com","_blank")
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Without the `http`[Exception... "The URI is malformed"  nsresult: "0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no] in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the protocol (in your example `http` or `https`).

```
window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com","_blank")
```

It's important for the browser to know if you're passing an absolute or relative uri. If it's absolute (like in your case), you have to prepend the protocol.