# Need to pass in url variable with Javascript to open new browser window

Tags: javascript, variables, window

I'm trying to open a window by passing in a variable url from the "demo" paragraph. I am probably doing something very obviously wrong but am very new to javascript. Any help much appreciated as this doesnt work!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo">www.google.com</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var name2 = encodeURIComponent(name);
window.open(name2, "_blank");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window.open only open url, does not click - click has to be done manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520996/window-open-only-open-url-does-not-click-click-has-to-be-done-manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "http://" string

```
window.open("http://"+name2, "_blank");
```

Comment: Better to insert correct url (with http/https) in demo div don't you think ?

Comment: Maybe... it depends on what he want to do with it